# Is it possible to increase the font size in iTunes?

Tags: itunes, font

How does one make the fonts that iTunes uses for things like app descriptions larger?  I know about Universal Access -> Zoom, but I'm looking for something a little more app-specific, like web browsers have.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to to change/customize every font/font-size within iTunes.app, that is used for the menu, pop-up dialogs, view-field etc..

In order to do so navigate to `/Applications/iTunes.app/Contents/Resources/English.lproj` and make a backup of **Localized.rsrc** first, just to be on the save side.

Then download [ThemePark3.1](http://www.geekspiff.com/download.php?product=themepark_3) in order to open and edit the **Localized.rsrc** file. Once you edited the font(s)/size to your liking, you need to save your changes from within ThemePark.

It might be, that you also need to reboot first to see the changes!!

[image]

---

**Edit:**
There is also an **iTunes.rsrc** file under `/Applications/iTunes.app/Contents/Resources/` which might be of help and lately **.css** stylesheet-files are being used for theming as well (in Linux (GTK3).

If that is also true for 10.7 (still running 10.6.8, therefore can only guess), please confirm this information!! Basically "simple" images can be drawn and rendered from code instead of using single image files, in png, tiff, jpg - format.

Those **.css** files also manage font information, like font-style, color values, size etc...

Comment: Thanks, but apparently I'm too dense to follow your instructions.  I couldn't find English.pliat, but found English.proj instead (as in the screenshot, title bar).  I still couldn't find Localized.rsrc there, or anywhere else on the machine, so I'm stuck.  Thanks, Ed.

Comment: Sorry Ed, my bad. It should have been English.lproj, as in the window header of the screenshot, so i edited my answer afterwards. Which version of iTunes do you use apparently and are you sure, that there is no "Localized.rsrc" within the path?!

Comment: Sorry, should have said earlier.  iTunes version: 10.5.3; OS version: 10.7.3.  As I said, no "Localized.rsrc" file in English.lproj, or anywhere else on the machine for that matter.  In fact, no .rsrc files period.  I'm obviously no guru, but from my web searches, they seem like possibly deprecated relics of older OS versions; should I be looking for a more modern equivalent?  Thanks, Ed.

Comment: It might be possible, that apple lately adopted css stylesheet-coding (which makes sense), instead of using repositories of images, font information etc.. I use an earlier version of iTunes and still use the latest 10.6 so i can't tell for sure, so i downloaded a theme for iTunes "10.5.3" which had an iTunes.rsrc under /Resources and also css files, which needed to be replaced.

Answer (score 1):

In the preferences window you can change the size of the Source and List Text.

Comment: Sorry, Tim, that doesn't help -- Source Text refers to the Source panel only (left side, lists the playlist names, etc.) and List Text refers to lists only (main arera, shows playlist content, etc., and only when in List views).  Neither applies to things like app descriptions.

Besides, the only choices there are Small and Large, which correspond to 8 and 10 points, respectively.

Thanks anyway,
  Ed

Answer (score 1):

The free application [TinkerTool](http://www.bresink.com/osx/0TinkerTool/download.php5) lets you edit system fonts and their sizes.  As a bonus, you don't need to go monkeying around with system files, because TinkerTool does it for you. (It'll work for certain, and you don't need to worry about, say, deleting something you don't want to.)

OTOH, it won't let you be app-specific in your preferences, but it *will* let you change the size of the text.
[image]

Comment: Thanks, Timothy, but I'm looking for something app-specific.  I don't need/want a system-wide change at this point.  Regards, Ed.